# Blade recursive view showing parent > child page as well as child page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hard to describe this in the title so this image might clarify:

[image: Multi select dropdown]

I have a recursive view which outputs the above:

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
    <option value="{{$page->id}}"
            @if($selected == $page->id) selected @endif
    >@for($i=0; $i<$levels; $i++)&#8618;@endfor {{$page->title}} (#{{$page->id}})
    </option>

    @if($page->children->count())
        @include('cms::admin.partials.page-selector-option', ['pages' => $page->children, 'levels' => $levels + 1])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Let's say that a page has the following columns:

- id
- parent_id
- title
- content
- template_id

The problem is that the collection of pages passed to this view e.g:

`$pages = Page::where('template_id', 10)->get()`

Contains a page with a child page of 'test subcat' which is being output as a child page correctly, but it also contains the subpage itself being output as a new item below (see both #54 pages loading in the screenshot).

Doing something like this:

`$pages = Page::where('template_id', 10)->where('parent_id', 0)->get()`

Does help, however I still want to show pages here that are not necessarily top level pages so may not have a `parent_id` of 0.

What I think I need to do is query the parent() relationship to see if the parent_id has the same template_id and if it does then do not return this item. Here's what I have so far which doesn't work:

```
  public function scopeWithoutChildren($query)
    {
        return $query->with(
            [
                'parent' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('template_id', '!=', 10);
                }
            ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it

```
public function scopeWithoutChildren($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('parent', function ($query) {
            return $query->where('parent_id', 'pages.parent_id');
        });
    }
```